# Pegar dados de duplicados de uma Coluna

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma tabela que eu tenho os campos customer_id e emails. Esses dois campos tem registros duplicados e estou fazendo um levantamento.
Preciso de ajuda pra pegar quantos registros de emails duplicados, mas com customer_id diferentes.
Se eu fizer um

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tabela GROUP BY EMAIL HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

posso pegar os emails duplicados mas com customer_id também iguais, o que não quero.

Alguém poderia me ajudar pelo menos com a lógica?

Comment: select * from tabela t1 where email in (select email from tabela t2 group by email having count(distinct t2.customer_id) > 1) order by t1.email , t1.customer_id , mas nem precisaria o distinct pois o id em tese é PK , para limpar duplicados tem N dicas na WEB , após limpar faça o email ser uma UNIQUE KEY , exemplo aqui mesmo no SOPT []´s

Answer (score 0):

Revisitando minha consulta, foi possível formular uma maneira mais eficiente:

```
SELECT a.id  FROM tabela a 
WHERE a.customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM tabela GROUP BY email, customer_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1);
```

Utilizando sua própria query como entrada para a solução do problema.
Para mais informações consulte a documentação do comando [IN](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions014.htm#SQLRF52169)